# re.findall printing the full text on a line of tekst

Tags: python

I got the following code:

```
import urllib
import re

html = urllib.urlopen("http://jshawl.com/python-playground/").read()

lines = [html]
for line in lines:
    if re.findall("jesseshawl", line):
        print line
```

My output when I run this code, is that it wil return the full website. How can I only display the row where it did found "jesseshawl". It should return something like:

```
jesseshawl@gmail.com
```

And is there a way to not return all html tags when I run this?

My output:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<h1>Some images to download:</h1>
<img src='python.gif'/><br />
<img src='terminal.png' />
<hr />

<h1>Email addresses to extract:</h1>
jesseshawl@gmail.com<br />
sudojesse@gmail.com<br />

<hr />

<h1>Login Form:</h1>
Login here:<br />
User: user<br />
Pass: pass
<form method="POST" action="login.php">
 User: <input type="text" name="username" /><br />
 Pass: <input type="password" name="password" /><br />
 <input type="submit" />
</form>

<h1>Memorable Quotes</h1>
<ul>
    <li></li>
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are reading the  whole page .S0 it prints all the thing .You have to read it line by line.There is no need for `findall` you can use `in` operator

**Code:**

```
import urllib
import re

html = urllib.urlopen("http://jshawl.com/python-playground/").readlines()
for line in html :
    if "jesseshawl" in line:
        print line
```

**Output:**

```
jesseshawl@gmail.com<br />
```

And if you don't want tags you could remove them using `sub`

**Code2:**

```
import urllib
import re

html = urllib.urlopen("http://jshawl.com/python-playground/").readlines()
for line in html :
    if "jesseshawl" in line:
        print re.sub("<[^>]*?>","",line)
```

**Output2:**

```
jesseshawl@gmail.com
```

Comment: You could only use `.` token instead of `[^>]`.

Comment: @Chaker yes but just being precautionary not to remove any other thing